# Cannot boot into Windows after Ubuntu 16.04 install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, uefi, bios

I am unfamiliar with Windows UEFI and changed the BIOS to Legacy to get my Lenovo B50 to boot from a USB port to install Ubuntu. Now the only way I can boot is to use UEFI in the BIOS to boot Windows and change it to legacy to boot Ubuntu. How can I fix this? Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: I don't think you can have a permanent solution while mixing the two boot systems.  you should decide which OS  you want to reinstall to be like the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

On my system I use F2 for UEFI, F8 for Boot Options and F10 for recovery. Yours likely has a boot option, too. What this does, is when I boot using F8, it pulls up my Win Boot Loader, Ubuntu USB and Ubuntu Boot-loader partition. After installing 16.04 (and until I get this grub2 fixed) I have to boot with F8 and choose Windows or Ubuntu respectively to boot into mine manually. Note, I am unable to do this when Secure Boot is active, so use F2 (UEFI option) and disable Secure Boot and see what happens.